# How to change IOS swipe back flutter?

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

right now the back button in ios is by swiping from left to right I want to change it to right to left. how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the other answer will work but it is hard to make it work and if you don't know swift it would be really tough.

the easier way to do this is to change its locale back to English (consider that your app language is rtl like Farsi or Arabic)

```
MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        supportedLocales: [
          Locale("en", "US"),
        ],
        locale: Locale("en", "US"),
```

then change your page  Directionality to rtl using `Directionality` widget.
like this

```
Directionality(
  textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
  child: Scaffold(
```

this will fix it

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing you want to create a right to left(RTL) application for example for arabic. Flutter supports the switch to RTL. Refer to the following:

[right-to-left (RTL) in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50535185/right-to-left-rtl-in-flutter)

[iOS back gesture for RTL Languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49625734/ios-back-gesture-for-rtl-languages)

Answer (score 0):

Check this package: https://pub.dev/packages/swipe_effect

```
SwipeEffect(
      direction: TextDirection.rtl, 
      color: Colors.green.withAlpha(70),
      verticalTolerance: 1.0,
      startDeltaPx: 30,
      callbackDeltaRatio: 0.25,
      callback: () {
        // Navigator.pop(context);
      },
      child: ...,
    );
```